# how to use spilt() function on const localRefsElement = React.createRefs();

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to split element whichever getting element from refs but when doing that time getting error like undefined property(reading 'split ')  if anyone know please tell.

in ReactJS i'm doing

Comment: You can't split an HTML element. The split function works on strings.

Comment: what is your ref returning ? is it a container ref that contains multiple elements ? Include your code please

Comment: Please elaborate more, show us the code, we need some details about the value you're passing to `createRef`